# Why after forwarding to port 80 for HTTP in my home modem, I can not use internet at all?

Tags: networking, router, internet, port-forwarding

Ok, I got modem from my Internet ISP. My goal is to host my website at home use my home PC rather than buying hosting services from third parties like Godaddy or HostGater...

So, first step, I entered `192.168.1.1` in browser and login my my modem management console.

Then I do the port forwarding as the below picture:

[image: 1]

After clicking "Save", I got an error message as following:

[image: 2]

Then when entering `192.168.1.1:8080`, I can see the info as the below picture:

[image: 3]

Now, before doing the port forwarding, I can access internet, but after doing that then I can not see anything when visiting any websites even big ones like facebook.com or yahoo.com. However, There is 1 exception. That is I still can enter Google.com

So, what did I do wrongly and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you access https://google.com? It'll be going over 443, not 80.

Comment: first step here is to reboot your router.  unplug it, wait 10 full seconds or so, then plug it in again.  do you magically have internet back?

Comment: This seems strange indeed. What are you options in the field 'use interface' when creating the Virtual Server rule in the router?

Comment: @Alex, u right, I still can go to Google.com but can not go to Yahoo.com

Comment: Use Interface has 2 options: ALL or pppoe_eth0/ppp0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not One-to-One NAT. This setup only routes traffic to/from the specified internal IP to the designated port on the router. If you use the default port for http traffic it'll clobber your browsing. As you noticed, accessing "https://google.com" still works because https operates over port 443.

Use 21000 or another unused port for your setup. Access your mapped private web server by hitting "http://[external ip]:21000". You can get your external IP by going to canihazip.com.

Note for people who use canihazip.com. They made the landing page fat. Use 'canihazip.com/s' when scripting.

DDNS: If you're going to use a domain name and haven't been given a static IP from your ISP you'll need to use DDNS to maintain the relationship between your domain name and your external IP. Without it your DNS records pointing to your external IP will break whenever the router is assigned a new address by your ISPs DHCP server.

---

The only other option that will allow regular port 80 web browsing is placing the web server in the DMZ. If you do that, be sure to setup iptables, or whatever firewall you're going to use very carefully. Only open up what's necessary. For details on managing the DMZ, refer to your router documentation. For general information on DMZ concepts and basic how-to, you can have a look at this: http://www.tp-link.us/article/?faqid=28

Comment: I m using No-IP.com, If I do the port forwarding on port 8080, and if I run the No-ip client, and if I start a Web server like Tomcat server then I can see tomcat page by going to xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080. However, I can not get rid of 8080. The only way to get rid of 8080 is to port forwarding the port 80, but then I will have the internet problem as mentioned above

Comment: your answer is interesting. But If I do like you said "http://[external ip]:21000" then How to get rid of 21000. You will not want average users to type ":21000" when visiting your domain right?

Comment: Well, the only other option that will allow regular port 80 web browsing is placing the host in the DMZ. If you do that, be sure to setup iptables, or whatever firewall you're going to use very carefully. Only open up what's necessary.

Comment: Can you update your answer and tell how to place the host in DMZ  properly as there is no info on internet mentioned that?

Comment: I did the DMZ, it works no need to type :8080 in the url. Thank u very much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

All I can say is your router is buggy. Port forwarding should only be applied to router's external IP and it seems some how it affected your outbound connections to port 80 as well.

I see that your router offers DMZ Host, that would be a potential alternative but all incoming traffic will be forwarded to it. So it could be dangerous.